# How can I set up Fabric.js in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fabricjs

I just came across the same combination: Fabric.js and Vue.js and was wondering, but I'm working with VueJs few days and I don't know how to set up fabric in vue.
Can you share some experience for me?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assuming you're using *ES6* and a bundler such as *Webpack* you can start using Fabric.js as follows:

At the command line

```
npm install fabric
```

or

```
yarn add fabric
```

Then import it in your **.js** file.

```
import { fabric } from 'fabric'
```

Then set up your `Canvas` in Vue's `mounted:` method.

*Note: For me the default `fabric` npm module resulted in quite a large package. I ended up using the `fabric-browseronly` module instead. Fabric.js has a lot of features you might not need, in which case you could build your own version [here](http://fabricjs.com/build/) or via the command line.*

Comment: Edit: `created` happens before the DOM gets painted so the component hadn't rendered a DOM to bind to yet...

Comment: this also works when installing fabric-browseronly via npm

Comment: I'm using Vue 3 with Vite, and when I use the import method I get: `SyntaxError: The requested module '/@modules/fabric/dist/fabric.js' does not provide an export named 'fabric'`

Comment: @WayneSmallman Perhaps things have progressed, as importing fabric into vue3 worked for me. "fabric": "^5.3.0", "vue": "^3.2.47" e.g. `<script setup> import { fabric } from 'fabric'`

Answer (score 22):

**Install Fabric**

```sh
yarn add fabric # or npm install -s fabric
```

**Basic component** (based on @laverick's answer):

```html
<template>
  <canvas ref="can" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
</template>

<script>
import { fabric } from 'fabric';

export default {
  mounted() {
    const ref = this.$refs.can;
    const canvas = new fabric.Canvas(ref);
    const rect = new fabric.Rect({
      fill: 'red',
      width: 20,
      height: 20
    });
    canvas.add(rect);
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: thank you so much, you helped me A LOT with this code

Comment: Is there equivalent code in this for Vue3?

Answer (score 0):

Fabric follows a pretty traditional distribution layout.

You want to use files from the `dist` directory. `fabric.js` for development work and `fabric.min.js` for the live site.