# How can I setup Fabric.js extension in Vue

Tags: vue.js, fabricjs

I already used Fabric.js in a Vue via directly import, similar to this 
[How can I set up Fabric.js in vue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42344356/how-can-i-set-up-fabric-js-in-vue)

Now I need to extend `fabric` object with the need to use this (the extension help to make curve text) https://github.com/EffEPi/fabric.curvedText

I tried to adapt from the source above and add it to my project as Vue Plugin, something like this

```
import "fabric";
import _Vue from "Vue";

export const FabricCurveTextPlugin = {
    install(Vue: typeof _Vue, options: object = {}) {
        // @ts-ignore
    const fabric = fabric || (fabric = {});
    const extend = fabric.util.object.extend;
```

I guess it won't work and it did't, I got the error 
`Uncaught Error: "fabric" is read-only...`

Would you share some experience to me how I could do it properly? Thanks

Comment: You may having permission issues. Check it our your permissions for the folder or something. If not retry install steps.

Answer (score 1):

From the github main page: 
https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js

Install with bower

```
$ bower install fabric
```

Install with npm
To install Fabric.js using npm, you must first manually install Cairo on your system. Cairo is a system library which powers node-canvas, which Fabric.js relies on. When the installation is complete, you may need to restart your terminal or command prompt before installing fabric.

```
$ npm install fabric --save
```

Have you did all the steps? Node is Ok?
Check it out the page, there is a lot of tips there:

Install Node.js, then install NPM, if necessary.

To install NPM packages

```
 $ npm install
```

Run test suite, make sure testem is installed

```
$ npm install -g testem
```

Tell me if it helps.

Comment: I installed successfully fabircJs and currently use it in Vue without any problem, the issue is, I need to some how extend the `fabric` global object to support more Object (eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36660108/how-to-create-custom-fabricjs-object).